# How to bake follow path constraint to animation keyframes

Tags: animation

[image: bake options available]

Hi everyone, I have been trying to bake a "follow path constraint" animation to keyframes in preparation for exporting to webgl formats. I have a path and I have added an object constraint "follow path" to my model, at which point it animates fine. I now have to bake this to key frames for use in webgl but i get nothing whatever I do with the bake options except an end and begining keyframe that are the same. I know this will be simple but I am just not seeing what I am doing wrong.
If you could provide any guidance I would be extremely greateful.
many thanks

Answer (score 7):

You should enable visual keying, as it reads in tooltip: 'Keyframe from the final transformations (with constraints applied)'

Comment: That worked a treat. many thanks calambre