How can I export a creation so that I can use it in another project with its transformations controllers still working?

I'm very new at this. In this collection, the highlighted "trackcontroller" empty sphere is what allows the wheels and track to move via its Rotation X with Transform Constraints.
Is there a way I can export this whole structure and keep the "trackcontroller" constraints working, so I can use it in another project file?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87194/i-finished-a-blender-project-how-do-i-export-it-with-all-the-features?rq=1

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

if my answer doesn't work, pls provide blend file. Normally this is the case if you didn't rig/build it correctly. e.g. if you are using global coordinates than local etc. You can check whether your object is "ok", if you move and rotate it and it stills works correct.

i assume by another "project file" you mean another Blender file, so move all meshes, constraints, empties etc. which belong to your mechanical object in one collection and name it e.g. "my export".
Open a new/other Blender file, choose file -> append -> collection -> "my export".
